# Creating tables in postgres DB using plpgsql fucntion

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Using pgAdmin III, I want to create tables in my postgres DB using a PL/pgSQL function specifically. The following set of commands does the job fine for me.

```
Create or Replace Function mk_tbl()
Returns Integer As $$
Declare
Begin
Drop Table if exists sel_streets;
Create Table sel_streets
(
id Integer,
Geom geometry
);
Create Index sel_streets_indx
ON sel_streets Using
gist (geom);
Return (1);
End $$ Language plpgsql volatile;
```

I am calling the function by this command:

```
Select mk_tbl();
```

My problem is every time I call this function, it creates tables in postgres DB as well as it returns '1' (in SQL editor output panel) which is not desired. I am aware that ultimately a function should return something and I can also use void construct like this:

```
Create or Replace Function mk_tbl()
Returns Void As $$
...
```

However, what I want is to call this function which should only create tables in my potgres DB and should return nothing. Is it possible to do this using PL/pgSQL specifically?

Comment: What you are looking for are "real" stored procedures. Unfortunately, Postgres does not support them, so you'll have to live with the `returns void` (Unrelated: the language name is an identifier, don't put it in single quotes: `language plpgsql` should be used).

Comment: I'm not sure if perform does not help you - `do $$ begin perform mk_tbl(); end;$$;`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Thank you for the correction. I have edited the code. Secondly, if I call this function using PL/Python or PL/R then is it possible to do this?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html - "...executes query and discards the result..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the problem with an empty result?

Using a `DO` statement would do what you want:

```
DO LANGUAGE plpgsql $$BEGIN
   PERFORM mk_tbl();
END;$$;
```

Comment: Well, thanks for your feedback and there is no problem with an empty result. But, it is good to run the query and discard the results. Similarly, I want to create table but without returning anything.

Comment: Perhaps you may want to update your answer about how to use this block of code. Either inside PLpgSQL or standalone. That would be more helpful for me to mark this as a valid answer because I am still unable to do what is required.

Comment: The statement in my answer is an SQL statement, you can run it like any other SQL statement. Running a `CREATE TABLE` statement never has a result.